# How to run PHP script on a GPU?

Tags: php, gpu, hardware

So, i'm working on a pattern recognition algorithm that uses and insane amount of processing.

I use this command to run scripts (100's of them);

```
exec("cd $rootDir; nohup php run_model.php $model_id > /dev/null 2> /dev/null &");
```

It takes a good 7 - 10 hours to run one of these scripts (I run 15 at a time). I am currently building a dedicated server for this programme to run on. Can anyone tell me how I can get the process above to run on a GPU.

Comment: Umm ... Does you're GPU support a PHP parser ??? I guess not ...

Comment: Alight Andre, no need for the sarcasm, I came here to ask because I obviously don't know if it can be done or not. if you want to make usless sarcy comments just for the sake of it log into YouTube. Stackoverflow is meant to be a community of people helping eachother to spread knowlage. get off.

Comment: Thanks for the help @HPierce very helpful, this question didn't come up when I Googled.